# applicationContext-service.xml problem definitions

Tags: java, spring

Working with spring, below, the code of applicationContext-service.xml:

```
<bean id="mediaObjectService" class="path.MediaObjectServiceImpl">

        <property name="mediaObjectDao" >
            <ref bean="mediaObjectDao"/>
        </property>
        <property name="semanticQuestionDao" >
            <ref bean="semanticQuestionDao"/>
        </property> 
        <aop:scoped-proxy/>
    </bean>
```

And while doing a test, I get his error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'scopedTarget.mediaObjectService'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [applicationContext-service.xml]:
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested
>   exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setInterceptDuringConstruction(Z)V

As I know, the session scoped objects always have a prefix called `scopedTarget.` to the name of the bean-id.
So, if I am right, `mediaObjectService` is the bean-id, which is right declarated.
Maybe I am wrong, but anyway, I don't see the error I made.

Any help??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following:

I was testing in a web application project in java. In this application, applicationContext-service.xml has the tag `<aop:scoped-proxy/>`, which help eliminate scope impedance mismatches.
This tag is not well fixed with JUnit tests, so the solution for me, at least for now, is testing this service in other application.

Thans anyway for your comments

Answer (score 5):

I used cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar and it solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

Google [suggests](http://i-proving.com/space/BC+Holmes/blog/2007-07-12_1) this may be due to duplicate versions of the cglib library on your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your tests are running with an incompatible version of `cglib.jar` on their classpath, and its clashing with Spring's expectations. Make sure you're using the correct version, which is most likely `2.1_3`.

Comment: I am using this version cglib-2.1_3.jar

Answer (score 0):

check the order in which cglib-2.1_3.jar has been defined in your .classpath file. Make sure it is defined before the spring jar's.